# Adding 2 different timestamp and dealing with PHP Datetime class

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I'm building an application that shows specific times on a given day. This application is meant to serve ppl worldwide.

I do all the calculation with a TZ in an hour format (-4 / 2 / 9.5 / -1 ETC). (don't worry. the hour tz is after DST calculations)

Now, I would like to show the user his local time. due to dev reasons, i can use only the hour tz for this calculation.

after a lot of tries,  i maneged to write a piece of code that seems to work. (tested it for few timezones, negetive and positive)

I am wondering if my code is ok? could i do it in a more efficent way? do this code support infinite date range?

here is the code:

```
     static function current_local_time_zmanim($tz)
/*
 * This function will get the number of hours off set (the time zone that Full_Zmanim_calculation() is using to make the calcukation) and will return the current local time and date.
 */ {
        $tz= ($tz * 3600);// calculatoin:  (hour offset(tz. can be -4 or 4) * 3600). eg: (-4*3600) or (3*3600)// converting the hour tz to TIMESTAMP 
        $date_utc = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone("UTC")); // current time in UTC. 
        $utctime= $date_utc->getTimestamp(); // current time in UTC TIMESTAMP
        $date_utc->setTimestamp($utctime + ($tz));// keep in mind that tz can be either positive or negetive
        $localtime= $date_utc->format('H:i');
        echo "<br> local time: $localtime <br> ";
        return $localtime;

    }
```

What do you think?

Thanks!

Comment: Out of interest, how do you know the users Timezone in PHP i.e. server side?

Comment: this application is only one part of a website. the website has a list of locations with al the neccecery details (lat lon tz (e.g -5) and tz olson db Id(America/new_york). this application is set to work either with hour tz or with olson tz id